# Sharing the same instance of a HTTP resource in a service?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a global service that is meant to hand out a single reference to a single, but possibly changing, object. Normally, I would do this via a "normal" input parameter of a component, but because a router is involved this is not possible. At least the following snippet didn't do anything to me, not even throwing an error:

```
<!-- All possible instances of this outlet have "project" set as input -->
<router-outlet [project]="project"></router-outlet>
```

Because I can't do it this way (please tell me otherwise if I could!), I created a service that I would like to use to share the same instance among all requesters. And apart from that I would love if I could get all observables out there to update with the new project, if a different project ID is requested. Obviously the code doesn't do this yet, because it replaces the whole cached Observable:

```
/**
* Wraps access to a whole project.
*/
@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {
    // The same instance should be shared among all projects
    private cache : {
        observable : Observable<Project>,
        id : string
    };

    /**
    * @param _http Dependently injected by Angular2
    */
    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    /**
    * @param id The id of the project to retrieve
    * @return An observable that updates itself if the selected project changes.
    */
    getProject(id : string) : Observable<Project> {
        if (!this.cache || this.cache.id != id) {
            let obs = this._http.get('/api/project/' + id)
                .do(res => console.log(res.json()))
                .map(res => new Project(res.json()))
                .catch(this.handleError);

            this.cache = {
                observable : obs,
                id : id
            }
        }

        return this.cache.observable.share();
    }

    private handleError (error: Response) {
        // in a real world app, we may send the error to some remote logging infrastructure
        // instead of just logging it to the console
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error);
    }
}
```

I was hoping that I could avoid subsequent HTTP requests by calling `share()` on the observable, but I guess I missunderstood something: Currently my app issues a new request for every call to `getProject()` with the same ID.

How could I get the service to:

- Not do any subsequent HTTP request after the first unless explicitly triggered?
- Update all subscribed Observables with a new resource instance if the requested id changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would update your service like that:

```
getProject(id : string) : Observable<Project> {
  if (!this.cache || this.cache.id != id) {
    return this._http.get('/api/project/' + id)
         .map(res => new Project(res.json()))
         .do((data) => {
           if (!this.cache) {
             this.cache = {};
           }
           this.cache[id] = data;
         })
         .catch(this.handleError);
  } else {
    return Observable.of(this.cache[id]);
  }
}
```

If you want to notify components that the data were updated, you could leverage a dedicated observable. And in the same time you set the cache, you could trigger an event with the associated observer... Components could subscribe on the observable to be notified.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want

```
getProject(id : string) : Observable<Project> {
    if (!this.cache || this.cache.id != id) {
        return this._http.get('/api/project/' + id)
            .do(res => console.log(res.json()))
            .map(res => new Project(res.json()))
            .map(res => return {
              observable : obs,
              id : id
             })
             .do(res => this.cache = res)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    } else {
      return Observable.of(this.cache);
    }
}
```